# Scrapy runs but doesn't crawl site - Scrapy Shell response in loop

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I've tried to set up Scrapy to crawl [a database for technical norm and standards](https://www.beuth.de/de/regelwerke/vdi/vdi-richtlinien-entwuerfe).

### **What is the problem:**

I wrote a Scraper, got a 200 response but no results - it scraped 0 pages:

```
2020-09-06 12:42:00 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: stack)
2020-09-06 12:42:00 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018), cryptography 2.4.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-09-06 12:42:00 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'stack', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'stack.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['stack.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
2020-09-06 12:42:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-09-06 12:42:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-09-06 12:42:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-09-06 12:42:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-09-06 12:42:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-09-06 12:42:01 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-09-06 12:42:01 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-09-06 12:42:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.beuth.de/de/regelwerke/vdi/vdi-richtlinien-entwuerfe> (referer: None)
2020-09-06 12:42:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-09-06 12:42:01 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 341,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 6149,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 6149,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 6, 10, 42, 1, 684021),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 6, 10, 42, 1, 140686)}
2020-09-06 12:42:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here are my items out of the *items.py* file which I want to scrape:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class StackItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    url = Field()
    date = Field()
    price = Field()
    subtitle = Field()
    description = Field()
```

**This my crawler code:**

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from stack.items import StackItem

class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["www.beuth.de"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.beuth.de/de/regelwerke/vdi/vdi-richtlinien-entwuerfe",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        elements = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="bwr-card__inner"]')

        for element in elements:
            item = StackItem()
            item['title'] = element.xpath('a[@class="bwr-link__label"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['url'] = element.xpath('a[@class="bwr-card__title-link"]/@href').extract()[0]
            item['date'] = element.xpath('div[@class="bwr-type__item bwr-type__item--light"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['price'] = element.xpath('div[@class="bwr-buybox__price-emph]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['subtitle'] = element.xpath('div[@class="bwr-card__subtitle bwr-data-dlink"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['description'] = element.xpath('div[@class="bwr-card__text bwr-rte bwr-data-dlink"]/text()').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

### **What I tried so solve the problem:**

1. I tried the Scrapy-Shell. After I used a defined User-Agent the website didn't block me:

> In [2]: from scrapy import Request
> ...: req = Request("https://www.beuth.de/de/regelwerke/vdi/vdi-richtlinien-entwuerfe",
> headers={"USER-AGENT" : "Mozi
> ...: lla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 OPR/45.0.
> ...: 2552.888"})
> ...: fetch(req)
> 2020-09-06 12:48:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.beuth.de/de/regelwerke/vdi/vdi-richtlinien-entwuerfe>](https://www.beuth.de/de/regelwerke/vdi/vdi-richtlinien-entwuerfe%3E)
> (referer: None)

After that I tested the selectors (see items list above) but unfortunately I just get a [] whatever XPath I use:

```
In [3]: response.xpath("//div[@class='bwr-buybox__price']/a/text").getall()
Out[3]: []
```

2. When I try *view(response)* I just a Browser Window with an infinite loading loop.
3. I tried to analyse the outcome but without an error I wasnt sure, where to start fixing.
4. I defined a User Agent in the *settings.py* because otherwise I got an error message about blocking (I think the website dont allow crawls).

### Summary:

I want to scrape the Items above from the list. But I am not sure if there is just a problem with my selectors because testing in Shell results in a [ ] everytime.

Comment: You can read the response you got by printing `response.body` in your shell. You will see that the response is mainly a javascript. Some pages use this type of method to prevent crawlers, they check if the browser can execute JS (which scrapy can't) before loading the page.  **I'm not saying this the case for this page**, as I just took a quick look. Parsing the JS yourself, may give you a better idea of what is happening.